# <ol> tags are nested together in template emberjs

Tags: xhtml, ember.js, handlebars.js

I want to create template for my view in Ember like: each ol tags will contain 4 items. I created it on jsfiddle.net with the URL: http://jsfiddle.net/secretlm/2C4c4/14/

But I don't know why ol tags are nested together and how to fix it. Thanks so much.

Comment: You might want to use `firstInGroup` and `lastInGroup` instead of `indexDivisible4` and `indexNotDivisible4` (respectively), those names will probably make more sense in six months and you could group them in sixes without having to rename the flags.

Comment: What do you mean? I don't understand clearly why you use them. What the differences?

Comment: For one, `indexNotDivisible4` is a lie since it is false when you're at index 2 but 2 is not divisible by 4. So your `indexNotDivisible4` is really saying "last one in the group" rather than "index is not divisible by 4", going with `firstInGroup` at the other end is just a consistency thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the mistake is on the indexNotDivisible4 function. I removed the `(idx == length - 1)`, and it seems to work. see http://jsfiddle.net/Sly7/2C4c4/20/

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That's work on jsfiddle.net. But when I run the same code (just different: model data which is given from my service and content which is the same model data I created), they are still nested together.

Comment: I found that  have the (idx == length - 1), the indexNotDivisible4 is still boolean (true or false) value.  Could you have any idea for this case? Thanks.

Comment: the `(idx==length-1)` tells the function to return true only if the object is the last one in the list. So all others are nested. I don't understand why it works in my fiddle, and don't in your app. Can you show the model data, and perhaps your service ?

Comment: I see an mistake which cause the problem in my app. Thank you anyway!